# Using Polymer UI Elements in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Is there a supported way to leverage polymer UI elements in dart?  It appears that polymer_element is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

> Currently Unsupported

at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_elements is misleading.

That's a project that Erik and I worked on a long time ago and the Dart team took over the project name not too long ago.

pub.dartlang.org shows always the content of the last release that isn't a pre-release. Pre-releases are versions that contain a `-` after the patch version like `1.0.0-beta.1`

The title shows

> polymer_elements 0.3.0 (latest: 0.3.0 / 1.0.0-rc.9 )

which means the latest release version is `0.3.0`, which is the unsupported one) and `1.0.0-rc.9` which is the pre-release one.

If you add a version constraint like

```
dependencies:
  polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.9
```

then you get the recent and supported version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This makes sense.  I've been very impressed with Dart capabilities and the shear number of iterations different parts of Dart have gone through.  The problem is that those iterations sometimes make how Dart and the supporting libraries work together quite confusing.

Comment: True, with new projects there is a lot of change untils things settle. Lot's of things are settling allready, lots keep changing, but that's also part of what makes Dart so exciting.